# how to render JSON object in react-native

Tags: api, react-native

in this page :https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest 
i can not render rates in text component ,
how to show rates in react native

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const coin = await Fetch.fetchCoins();
  this.setState({coin});
} 

{this.props.shop.map((item)=>{
  return( 
    <View key={item.base}>
      <Text>{item.date}</Text>
      <Text>{item.rates}</Text>
    </View>
  )
 })
}
```

Comment: What sort of component? What are you trying? Please add the relevant code.

Comment: i will use text component to show rate but can not get element ex :NZD value

Comment: please add your code to the post

Comment: async componentDidMount(){
        const coin = await  Fetch.fetchCoins();
        this.setState({coin});
    }                           {this.props.shop.map((item)=>{
                return(
                    <View key={item.base}>
                    <Text>{item.date}</Text>  
                    <Text>{item.rates}</Text>                 
                    </View>
              
                )
            })}

Comment: It looks like this is an incomplete example, but a couple of potential issues: 1) assuming the second bit of code is actually part of `render`, are you actually iterating over `this.state.coin`? 2) `rates` is an object, which you need to iterate over as well

Comment: if you want to write this code how to write it ? i am confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as `rates` is an object, I would recommend adding a function approximately something like the following:

```
renderRates = (rates) => {
  let rows = [];
  Object.keys(rates).forEach(key => {
                                rows.push(<Text>{key + ' ' + rates[key]}</Text>)
                             });
  return rows;
}
```

and then replacing `<Text>{item.rates}</Text>` with `{this.renderRates(this.coin.rates)}`